# Mysql Workbench, exporting selected rows of a table

Tags: mysql, export, dump, workbench

I already know how to export the whole database, but how do you export selected rows?

Say I need to export data from this queries: select * from users where gender="0"; How do you do turn them into a dump file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Easy way to do that:

Execute your query. In your case `select * from users where gender="0";`

In result section you will find `File:` option. There you will get `Export record set to an external file`. Click here and save your file in your desired extension.

Thats all.

Comment: what this option is only exporting 1000 records i.e. the limit of select. But i have around 5 lakhs record to export. How to do the same?

Comment: @dhroove Sorry for late response. Just select "Don't Limit" from the tool bar of Workbench.

Comment: @ArifulIslam: yup.. was able to figure out that day. But many thanks for the reply.